# JavaFX Netbeans FXML not found

Tags: javafx

Hello everyone i am learning javafx and i am having issue to run simple basic program of hello world i know that javafx works in MVC type structure which fxml,mainclass, and controller so what i am doing is i just created the first program in JavaFX in which 3 things were there a HelloWorld.Java , HelloWorld.fxml and HelloWorldController.java and  creating a com.bean package for HelloWorld.java and com.gui for HelloWorld.fxml and com.controller for HelloWorldController.java but i am facing an issue while i am running it it shows an exception that fxml is not loaded a location is required.....please help i also bild and cleaned it many time but not working.....

HelloWorld.java

```
    package com.bean;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


/**
 *
 * @author Love Poet
 */
public class HelloWorld extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("com/gui/HelloWorld.fxml"));
        Scene scene=new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Hellow World Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
    package com.controller;

/**
 * Sample Skeleton for 'HelloWorld.fxml' Controller Class
 */

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloWorldController implements Initializable{
    @FXML // fx:id="button"
    private Button button; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="label"
    private Label label; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Hello World !");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
}
```

HelloWorld.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import com.controller.*?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="HelloWorldController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="129.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="211.0" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="35.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="274.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

for this i am using netbeans my structure of doing this is :-

[This is an image of netbeans project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u8CW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a class in the `com.bean` to get the resource, which means using the relative path `com/gui/HelloWorld.fxml` creates a url that would point to the `HelloWorld.fxml` in the `com.bean.com.gui` package.

In this case you either need to use the `ClassLoader` with the same relative path:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/gui/HelloWorld.fxml")
```

or use a path relative to the classpath root

```
this.getClass().getResource("/com/gui/HelloWorld.fxml")
```

Comment: i done all this and this is not a solution and i already found the solution to this issue myself well thanks for your reply the solution is simple to edit fxml in netbeans not to open just edit it as in text editor and the fx-controller in borderpane you have to pass the path of your controller and then after the the step you said to give the classpath the program will run